# Error in acorr_ljungbox from statsmodel

Tags: python, statsmodels

So I am trying to do a box-ljung test on a resudual, but I am getting a strange error and am not able to figure out why.

```
x = diag.acorr_ljungbox(np.random.random(20))
```

I tried doing the same with a random array also, still the same error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (19,) (40,)
```

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code

Comment: The issue is because the function takes lag=40 by default and the array was shorter than that. It is solved if you explicitly set the lag. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the default lag setting, which is set to 40 independent of the length of the data.

As a workaround and to get a proper statistic, the `lags` needs to be restricted, e.g. using 5 lags below.

```
>>> from statsmodels.stats import diagnostic as diag

>>> diag.acorr_ljungbox(np.random.random(50))[0].shape
(40,)

>>> diag.acorr_ljungbox(np.random.random(20), lags=5)
(array([ 0.36718151,  1.02009595,  1.23734092,  3.75338034,  4.35387236]),
array([ 0.54454461,  0.60046677,  0.74406305,  0.44040973,  0.49966951]))
```

Comment: this is now reported here  https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3229